# Is my PCB shorting to ground?

Tags: pcb, lithium-ion, battery-operated, short-circuit

I am working on a senior design project that utilizes a 3.7V lithium ion battery. Before I connect to the board, the pins show 3.7V (as expected). When I plug the battery into the connector, measure the voltage across the terminals of the connector, I see 0V. Is something shorted? I have tested all traces to check continuity with ground, with no issues. Any and all ideas are appreciated.

Comment: If you're measuring 0 V across the terminals of a lithium battery that formerly showed 3.7 V, you should see smoke somewhere. That you don't report any suggests an intermittent open circuit or high resistance in the battery leads. Ah! unless it's a protected lithium, which may well shut down into a short. Which type is it?

Comment: did you measure the resistance between the battery connector pins on the PCB before you connected the battery?

Comment: What do you measure on the battery when it's not plugged in?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A picture of your project would help us help you.